# Successive $http posts in service sending the same parameters twice

Tags: angularjs, http, coffeescript, http-headers, http-request

Using Angular 1.2.7, I have written a service to upload files to s3: files are chosen in the interface with a multiple file input field, and the service is called for each of the files in a loop in the controller:

```
      for file, index in $files
        cloudUpload.uploadToS3(
          file,
          index
      )
```

In my service:

```
    signS3File: (file) ->
      #create the uploadData array...
      #...
      #generate unique uploadData for this particular file
      return $http(
        method: 'POST'
        url: '/api/s3_signing'
        data: uploadData
      )

    uploadToS3: (file, index) ->
      @signS3File(file)
        .then(do some more stuff)
```

All of this works pretty well, but I have one problem:

When I look at what gets generated in uploadData each time the function is called, the data is unique and corresponds to what I want to send. However, when I inspect the requests made by $http, it turns out that the uploadData used is always the same one (I think it's the one of the last $http call). I really don't understand why, if uploadData is correct, why $http always send the same data!

To illustrate a bit more, here are the console.logs of each of the uploadData variables that get created:

```
Object {... file_name: "80RT2ebgkX2QQMGcxi4U0rqumZuUWblF.mp3"}
Object {... file_name: "7O6QBlMSDpRA4rS5UgPVDEdIIwmRkV0t.mp3"}
```

and here is the data sent by the requests (same for both requests, which is my problem):

```
...
file_name: "7O6QBlMSDpRA4rS5UgPVDEdIIwmRkV0t.mp3"
```

edit: using $http.post(...) instead of $http(method: "post"...) has the same result.

edit: I have moved the s3signing function from the service to the controller, and it behaves properly: It is probably, as Caleb suggested, a scope issue - I welcome ideas though, having the signing in the controller is not ideal!

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: hey calebboyd! I'm using 1.2.7

Comment: This sounds like it might be a scope problem. Maybe within `$http` I was just going to ask for the information you just gave... haha

Comment: oh ok - I was wondering if there would be some way to "force" http to use the newly generated uploadData array or something... I've even tried to put the uploadData itself in an array using the index to make absolutely sure that we refer to a different variable, but to no avail. !

Comment: Try, for fun.. `return $http.post(url,data)` This is a different closure internally.

Comment: I actually tried this one as well, I was originally using $http.post before and changed it to the other form to see if it would make a difference :/ thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Could be caused by where coffee script hoists your variable declarations.. But I don't use CS.. so that statement might not even make sense.

Comment: maybe actually! I'll have a look and see what's going on - putting the function in the controller is actually not really working neither :/